# I want to make my whole textarea content visible

Tags: html, jsp, textarea

I'm placing description on a text area by retrieving database using jsp, like follows;

```
<textarea readonly=""><%= item.getContent() %></textarea>
```

so I want to show the whole content of textarea in page without scroll bar, how can I do it?

Comment: Try `overflow: visible` on the textarea

Comment: I tried this one, but it's not working as I expected..

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following link
http://jsfiddle.net/TDAcr/

```
<head>
<title>autoresizing textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
border: 0 none white;
overflow-y: auto;
padding: 0;
outline: none;
background-color: #D0D0D0;
resize: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init (maxH) {
        var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var maxHeight=maxH;
    var oldHeight=  text.scrollHeight;
    var newHeight;
    function resize () {

    text.style.height = 'auto';
    newHeight= text.scrollHeight;
    if(newHeight>oldHeight && newHeight>maxHeight  )
    {
        text.style.height=oldHeight+'px';

    }
    else{
        text.style.height = newHeight+'px';
        oldHeight=  text.scrollHeight;
    }

    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init(200);">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```